# Is there a way to undo a p4 labelsync?

Tags: perforce

I accidentally a label:

```
p4 labelsync -l foobar-rc3
```

How can I bring the label's files back to the revisions they were at before I labelsynced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's easy to undo.  You can lock labels to prevent accidental modification, of course.  If it's critical you should ask Perforce support, as they might have a trick I haven't heard of.

Comment: Accepting your answer since no one seems to know--there probably isn't a way.  Thanks!